# SQL Between Begins With

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, between

I'm attempting to use an alpha between in SQL; however, I want it to be based on the beginnings of the words only. I am using T-SQL on Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

My current SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LEFT(word,1) BETWEEN 'a' AND 't
```

However, this only works for first letter. I'd like to expand this to work for any beginnings of words. For instance, between 'a' and 'ter'.
Now, I am building this dynamically, so I could do:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LEFT(word,1) >= 'a' AND LEFT(word,3) <= 'ter'
```

However, I'd like to know if there is a simpler way in SQL to make a dynamic beginning-of-word between.

EDIT:::

Follow up question, words less than the length of the checked value should be considered less than in the between. For instance, me is less than mem so word < 'mem' should include me.

EDIT:::
Attempting using padding, as suggested. The below does work; however, the added 'a's can cause issue. For instance, if we want words between 'a' and 'mera' and the word being checked is 'mer', this will be included because the left trim of 'mer' becomes 'mera' with added characters. I would like a solution that does not include this issue.

```
DECLARE @lb varchar(50)
DECLARE @ub varchar(50)

SET @lb='ly'
SET @ub='z'

SELECT name
FROM table
WHERE
LEFT(
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(name) < LEN(@lb) THEN name+REPLICATE('a',LEN(@lb)-LEN(name))
        ELSE name
    END,
    LEN(@lb)
) >= @lb
AND
LEFT(CASE
        WHEN LEN(name) < LEN(@ub) THEN name+REPLICATE('a',LEN(@ub)-LEN(name))
        ELSE name
    END,
    LEN(@ub)
) <= @ub
```

EDIT:::
Attempted solution, although CASE heavy. Mack's solution is better, though this works as well. LEFT('andy', 200000) will return 'andy', not an error as an OO language would, behavior I did not expect.

```
DECLARE @lb varchar(50)
DECLARE @ub varchar(50)

SET @lb='a'
SET @ub='lyar'

SELECT *
FROM testtable
WHERE
CASE
    WHEN LEN(word) < LEN(@lb) THEN 0
    WHEN LEFT(word, LEN(@lb)) >= @lb THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END = 1
AND
CASE
    WHEN LEN(word) < LEN(@ub) THEN
        CASE
            WHEN LEFT(@ub,LEN(word)) = word THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    WHEN LEFT(word, LEN(@ub)) <= @ub THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END = 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ... All the existing answers will _potentially_ ignore any indices on `word` due to the use of functions (although SQL Server might be smart enough to not care about `LEFT()`).  Personally, I'd just pad the shorter string with upper/lower bound characters (although depending on what's considered 'valid' data, you may need to get the 'next' character and use less-than, as with timestamps)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I agree regarding the existing answers. I believe I've found a solution using CASE that should allow for any instances to be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [STUFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function to achieve what you are looking for explicitly.
If you follow the link says it deletes a specified number of characters at the end of the string and replaces them with another string.  Combine the with the LEN function and we can get you on the road.

```
--Test Data
DECLARE @table AS TABLE (word char(10))

INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('me')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('mem')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('tap')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('t')

DECLARE @minword char(5)
DECLARE @maxword char(5)

SET @minword='ai'
SET @maxword='t'
--SET @maxword='tb'--(remove the rem at the start of this line to unlock an extra test for comparison...)

--Query
SELECT word
FROM @table 
WHERE STUFF(word, LEN(word)+1, 5, 'aaaaa') BETWEEN STUFF(@minword, LEN(@minword)+1, 5, 'aaaaa') 
                                               AND STUFF(@maxword, LEN(@maxword)+1, 5, 'aaaaa')
```

Alternative solution based on your revised requirements:

```
DECLARE @testtable AS TABLE (word varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @testtable VALUES ('ly')
INSERT INTO @testtable VALUES ('Ly')
INSERT INTO @testtable VALUES ('Zoo')
INSERT INTO @testtable VALUES ('r')
INSERT INTO @testtable VALUES ('traci')

DECLARE @minword varchar(20)
DECLARE @maxword varchar(20)

SET @minword='ly'
SET @maxword='zol'

SELECT word, LEFT(word,LEN(@minword)), LEFT(word,LEN(@maxword)), @minword, @maxword
FROM @testtable 
WHERE LEFT(word,LEN(@minword))>=@minword
AND  LEFT(word,LEN(@maxword))<=@maxword
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work as I need. Why is 5 the arbitrary addition? Shouldn't I add a's to word to make it the same length as either min or max word, whichever is larger? I agree, stuff might be the best method.

Comment: The aaaaa's are to set the word to the lowest value possible as per your question. There are five in this example as this is the length of the parameter, you would need to modify this to match your specific requirements.  If you include your own schema in the question, we can help with more specific answers.

Comment: The upper and lower bounds are parameters. The statement is built and run using and SqlCommand in c# ASP.NET codebehind.

Comment: If you can let me know the datatype and size of the column you are querying against I can adjust the query accordingly.  Alternatively here's a SQL Fiddle I have just set up using my example above. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f20e/4  Have a play around with it.

Comment: I've adjusted your sql fiddle accordingly http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb73c. The schema is corrected. Really though, this method should work across the board, regardless of schema. I've attempting something similar above and added to my edits with the one issue I encountered.

Comment: Based on the dataset in your fiddle and the parameters in your question ('ly' and 'z') would you expect everything apart from 'zoo' to be returned?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42963/discussion-between-mack-and-steventnorris)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LEFT(word,3) BETWEEN 'a' AND 'ter'
```

There's no reason why BETWEEN shouldn't be able to compare your three-letter data string to the one-letter 'a'. Any 'axx' will be "greater than" just 'a' by itself, and so will be included.

Comment: That will work for that instance, but not across the board. Say for instance I have between ai and t inclusive, the first two letters won't be less than t, and thus any words beginning in t are not included.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you are trying to make this into a proc.  If so, what you have will work in a proc with very little change.  Something like the following (untested)...

```
CREATE PROC myProc(@low varchar(30), @high varchar(30)) AS 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
   (LEN(word) >= LEN(@low)
   AND 
   (LEN(word) >= LEN(@high)
   AND 
   (LEFT(word, LEN(@low)) >= @low) 
   AND 
   LEFT(word, LEN(@high)) <= @high
```

There are additional conditions to exclude records when 'word' is shorter than either of your parameters.  Otherwise, you will get errors on the LEFT function.  This may not be 100% but it should get you close.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. I do have a follow up question though, how would I deal with making words of lower length less than rather than ignoring? For instance, me is less that mem, so word < mem would include me.

Comment: I'm not where I can run a test but off the top of my head I think you would drop the first two conditions in the where clause and then use MIN.  So it would be something like:  LEFT(word, MIN(LEN(word), LEN(@high))) <= @high

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found a working solution. I'm not sure of the speed sacrifices here, but the DB will remain small, so it's a non-issue in my specific case.

I am using C# to build my SQL string with parameters. @lb is the lower bound word-part. @rb is the upper bound word-part. The where clause is inclusive, but could easily be change to exclusive as needed.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
CASE
    WHEN LEN(word) < LEN(@lb) THEN 0
    WHEN LEFT(word, LEN(@lb)) >= @lb THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END = 1
AND
CASE
    WHEN LEN(word) < LEN(@rb) THEN 1
    WHEN LEFT(word, LEN(@rb)) <= @rb THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END = 1
```

Comment: Hmmm....  you should be able to change these into regular conditions (each `CASE` is an `OR`).  I assume that this works for your purposes, but it'd surprise me somewhat - if `@lb` is `'an'` and `@rb` (should probably be **u**pper-*b*ound) is ``'star'`, things like `'zoo'` are included; I was anticipating behavior similar to a dictionary (strictly alphabetical).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Wow, you're right. I missed that. Padding the words with 'a's might work better then, as suggested by yourself and Mack below.